# After renaming a parameter, runtime refers to old name, that does not exist anywhere in my code

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have a razor component. The component have a parameter, `EventCallback` to be precise, named "ValueChanged".

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

I refer to the event exactly in one razor file like this:

```
<Autocomplete DataSource="@Data" Columns="Id,Name" ValueChanged="OnUnitBrandIdChanged" />
```

I renamed (via F2, AKA refactor) the property name to "OnValueChanged". The razor file was not automatically updated (I guess a bug in Visual Studio). So I updated it manually. So now both points of interest looks like this:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> OnValueChanged { get; set; }
```

and

```
<Autocomplete DataSource="@Data" Columns="Id,Name" OnValueChanged="OnUnitBrandIdChanged" />
```

The code compiles and runs, then the runtime crashes with following error message

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type 'Woof.Blazor.Components.Autocomplete' does not have a property matching the name 'ValueChanged'.

I wasted 4 hours investigating the case.
First, I changed the name "OnValueChanged" to "SomethingElse" - to make sure, the string "ValueChanged" doesn't exist in my source code at all.
Of course I get the same error message.

Then I searched ALL files in my project, including hidden and binary files for the string "ValueChanged". Of course I found the string in `obj`, `bin` and `.vs` directories. So I deleted those files.

After compiling the code again, I get the same error message. The one with 'ValueChanged' reference.

I created completely new Blazor project. I copied all my code files, triple-checking NONE of them contains "ValueChanged" string.

When the new project is run - I get the same error message.

I thought maybe Visual Studio has written the reference in a file outside the project directory in a hidden place. So I remove all temporary files from the project, published it on GitHub and send to my coworker. He cloned the project, run it and got the same error message.

I created the property with the name "ValueChanged", dummy property, `object` type. Completely unused and redundant. Of course program runs without errors.

It appears the reference to that name is hidden somewhere but I have no idea where. No Windows tool is able to search "ValueChanged" string within project directory. I even suspected the Visual Studio could hide the reference by encrypting and / or compressing the content, but again I triple-checked I removed ALL binary files, all non plain text files.

All for nothing.

Then I created completely new Blazor project. Created a test component, created an event, bound dummy event handler, compiled and run. Everything worked. Then I refactored my test program in the exact same way as the original one. It worked, no problems at all. I even used exactly the same names, types, directory structure, namespaces, I even added the parameter named "Value" to make my test case more similar to the production code. The result is the new project behaves normally. I can rename any parameter and it just works.

My old project doesn't behave normally even when it's almost rewritten from scratch WITHOUT the string "ValueChanged" occurring in any file ONCE. The same error message. Like with Visual Studio and Blazor the common logic no longer applies. The name doesn't exist, but when I compile the code, it suddenly appears in temporary files with `g.cs` extension.

It's most probably a horrific bug in Visual Studio / .NET Core, but to report it I should be able to reproduce it, but in this case - I can't. Any clues?

BTW, Of course I tried to debug it and set the breakpoint on the cursed property setter. It gets triggered, however the only items in my call stack are "External code", so it's completely useless.

Comment: did you clean VS Cache? It's in %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

Comment: Are you omitting anything? The Blazor framework expects any parameter involved in binding to have a matching event callback called .. Changed. So a parameter called Value should have a corresponding parameter called ValueChanged. The error implies you have a Value that is being bound somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note the following:

You ordinarily define a parameter property in a component if this component is a child component which is bound to a parent component, in that case the parent component is bound to a Value property that should be defined in the child component, and decorated with the Parameter attribute as well. Thus, your child component should look like this

```
private string _value;

[Parameter]
public string Value
{
    get { return _value ?? string.Empty; }
    set
    {
        if (Value != value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

The following is the usage of the component in a parent component

```
<ChildComponent @bind-Value="value" />

@code 
{
    private string value;
}
```

Note: The code above (ParentComponent) embed the child component defined before, and bind the local variable called value to the Value property of the child component. When you want to bind to a property of a `Component` from a parent component you use the @bind directive + hyphen + the name of the property, as for instance: @bind-Password="password". In the bounded component (the child component) you should define the property (in the last instance it should be Password) and a delegate parameter property (in the last instance it should be

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> PasswordChanged { get; set; }
```

)
As you can see, we must have this pair. BUT ValueChanged or PasswordChanged are constructs which the compiler use to produce, behind the scene, code which enables communication between a parent component and a child component. To be more precise, the compiler produces code that enable two way data-binding between the components... You can't use ValueChanged or PasswordChanged as an attribute for event handlers. The only thing you can do is trigger the delegates. Thus you can put an input `element` in your child component, and bind the value attribute of the input element to the Value property of the component, like this:

```
<input type="text" value="@Value" @oninput="OnValueChanged" />
```

This is a one-way binding from the *Value* property of the child component to the *value* attribute of the element. We also have to update the Value property, in that case, whenever the user type a char... For this we need to define an event handler, which is called after each hit on the keyboard, like this:

```
private Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    Value= e.Value.ToString();

    return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
}
```

As you can see, the OnValueChanged method assign the value entered into the text box (this is done at each hit on the keyboard) into the Value property, and then.....................
triggers the **ValueChanged** delegate, passing it the value of the Value property. This is what you should do with **ValueChanged**, nothing else. Now, when the delegate is triggered, the value of the private value field in the parent component is updated with the value of the Value property of the child Component. This procedure is called two ways data-binding between **Components**